# Date format issue in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, date

I have this query in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, '2017-05-10');
```

I have run my code today and remarked that the result looks like '2017-08-05' instead of '2017-03-10' expected. It seems like date format turned into yyyy-dd-mm before conversion and returned back to yyyy-mm-dd to display the result.

Is there any explanation? How to fix this definitely?

Comment: Try using the *modified* **ISO-8601** format for dates as string literals only: `SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, '20171005');` (format is `YYYYMMDD` - no dashes, no spaces). This works reliably for **all** language and regional settings for any version of SQL Server

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, CAST('2017-05-10' as datetime))` Will cast as the datetime first, then subtract the two months. @marc_s has a good answer if you can format your data, otherwise you'll have to do some CAST or CONVERT first probably.

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s. I was making tests first on sql server 2012, and `DATEADD(mm, -2, '2017-05-10')` was returning `2017-03-10`, what I expected. Version issue.

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: @Reyan Chougle, my input is in yyyy-mm-dd format. But, according to the result, it's like if the function consider yyyy-dd-mm format.

Comment: @sk001 Please check my post

Comment: Thank you all, the answer of @sepupic solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you talking about is not a **date** format issue, but **datetime** issue, in fact, if you try this code you'll ALWAYS get the same result:

```
set dateformat ymd
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, cast('2017-05-10' as date));

set dateformat ydm
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, cast('2017-05-10' as date));
```

While using **datetime** you'll get different results depending on your language/dateformat setting:

```
set language us_english
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, '2017-05-10');

set language russian
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -2, '2017-05-10');
```

**The format yyyy-mm-dd** is language neutral when using with date type but it's **language dependent when using with datetime**.

**Explanation:**

> It is important to note that some character string formats of date and
>   time literals are language  dependent, meaning that when you convert
>   them to a date and time data type, SQL Server might  interpret the
>   value differently based on the language setting in effect in the
>   session. Each logon defined by the database administrator has a
>   default language associated with it, and unless it is changed 
>   explicitly, that language becomes the effective language in the
>   session. You can overwrite the default  language in your session by
>   using the SET LANGUAGE command, but this is generally not recom-
>   mended because some aspects of the code might rely on the user’s
>   default language.  The effective language in the session sets several
>   language-related settings behind the scenes,  among them one called
>   DATEFORMAT, which determines how SQL Server interprets the liter- als
>   you enter when they are converted from a character string type to a
>   date and time type. The  DATEFORMAT setting is expressed as a
>   combination of the characters d, m, and y. For example, the 
>   us_english language setting sets the DATEFORMAT to mdy, whereas the
>   British language setting  sets the DATEFORMAT to dmy. You can override
>   the DATEFORMAT setting in your session by using  the SET DATEFORMAT
>   command, but as mentioned earlier, changing language-related settings
>   is  generally not recommended. Consider, for example, the literal
>   ‘02/12/2007’. SQL Server can interpret the date as either February
>   12, 2007 or December 2, 2007 when you convert this literal to one of
>   the following types:  DATETIME, DATE, DATETIME2, or DATETIMEOFFSET.
>   The effective LANGUAGE/DATEFORMAT setting  is the determining factor.
>   To demonstrate different interpretations of the same character string
>   literal,  run the following code. SET LANGUAGE British;  SELECT
>   CAST('02/12/2007' AS DATETIME);    SET LANGUAGE us_english;  SELECT
>   CAST('02/12/2007' AS DATETIME);

Related article: [Working with Date and Time Data by Itzik Ben-Gan](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2225058&seqNum=7)

Following the link you'll find the table with language-neutral formats for different date/time types